# Переменная не записывается в базу данных внутри блока php

Tags: php, url

Всем привет, такая проблема, у меня есть блок, и он выполняется если условие верно. Так вот, у меня есть переменная, взятая из url, и вне if блока она записывается, а внутри нет, когда остальные переменные внутри блока записываются в бд.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<?php
    include 'index.html';
    include 'rb.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=*; charset=UTF8", '*', '*');
    if (isset($_POST['comment'])){
        //переменная username, которая не записывается.
        $username = $_GET['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $date = date('H:i:s');
        $query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO *.comments (`username`, `comment`, `data`) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date')");
    }
    $comments = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM *.comments ORDER BY data DESC");
    $comments = $comments->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($comments){
        foreach($comments as $comment){
            echo $comment['username'];
            echo '<br>';
            echo $comment['comment'];
            echo '<br>';
            echo $comment['data'];
            echo '<br>';
        }        
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: А не `$_POST['username']` должно быть?

Comment: И что значит "вне блока"? Разве ты не должен выполнять insert-запрос как раз в блоке `if`, только тогда у тебя есть все нужные данные.

Comment: Ну я же беру username из url, поэтому GET

Comment: Вне блока if\\\

Comment: Я __повторю__ вопрос: почему  insert-запрос выполняется __снаружи__ блока if? Именно в блоке if у тебя есть все нужные переменные - коммент, юзернейм, дата.

Comment: Поправил, поместил в if блок, всё также

Comment: Тогда проверь что выводит `print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET);` в блоке if.

Comment: Array ( ) Array ( [username] => a )

Comment: По идее, если Вы пишете `print_r($_POST);` внутри блока if, то результатом не может быть пустой массив `Array ( )`, так как для выполения кода внутри блока if, есть условие `isset($_POST['comment'])`.

Comment: Тем не менее, он пустой

Comment: Мой комментарий был о том, что Вас попросили сделать `print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET);` внутри блока с условием if, Вы его сделали вне блока с этим условием. Вас просят сделать одно, Вы делаете другое, а потом удивляетесь неожиданному поведению.

Comment: Откуда вы знаете, что я написал вне этого блока? Я всё написал куда надо, в if блок

Comment: Я знаю, потому что если срабатывает условие `if (isset($_POST['comment'])){}` то `print_r($_POST);` не может быть пустым массивом `Array( )`, потому что в таком случае это условие не сработало бы и Вам бы не вывело результат `print_r()`.

Comment: Нет, print_r в блоке if

Comment: Прочитайте код который Вы сами написали, внимательно) Вы же понимаете как работает это условие `if (isset($_POST['comment'])){}` или нет? Это значит что в массиве `$_POST` присутствует элемент массива с ключем `comment`, то есть `$_POST['comment']`, если он есть и условие `isset()` сработало, то он должен быть в результатах `print_r()` так как массив `$_POST` не пустой, либо тогда он Вам вывел не `Array ( ) Array ( [username] => a )`.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @Simon. Либо вывод не там, либо уже какой-то иной код тестируется.

Comment: Всё равно дело не в POST, мне важна переменная username из GET